# Calculating total salary with Libre Office Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I store my working time in Libre Office Calc like this:

```
Start   End     Hours
10:00   15:00   05:00
11:00   14:00   03:00
09:30   15:30   06:00

Total
14:00
```

Now I want to calculate my salary, i.e. multiply the total hours with for example 10 (salary per 1 hour).
When I try:

```
=G2*10 // (G2 is the cell with the total hours 14:00)
```

I get a total salary of 5,83 € (the cell is already formatted as currency). I don't know where this strange amount comes from.

Comment: What is the unformatted (or number formatted) value of G2?  Dates/times can be handled a little goofy in spreadsheet programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view your 14:00 hours in their stored form, you will see 0,583333333333333; times are stored as fraction of a day and formatted to appear as common units.  The number comes from division of 14 hours by 24 hours in a day; `14/24=0.58333`.  So if you multiply by 10 you get 5,83 €.

The answer is to change your formula to turn the fraction of a day into number of hours:

```
 =G2*24*10
```